# probability of penalty (in soccer) being scored or being missed

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution, negative-binomial

I have the following assumptions.
I am expecting 0.4 penalties in a match on average, and I am assuming that penalties follow a Poisson distribution. The probability of a penalty being converted is 82%. 
What is the probability of having a scored in the match?

I know using Poisson pdf that the probability of having no penalty is 0.67032

`poisson(λ = 0.4, x = 0)`

so the probability of having at least one is the remaining 0.32968

So I guess I need the conditional probability
P(penalty scored / penalty awarded)

my guess is
`p(awarded) * p (converted)` for the first case and
`p(awarded) * (1 - p(converted))` for the second case of having a missing penalty

What do you think, how should I calculate those conditional probabilities?

Comment: We need more details on the setup: what is the probability of scoring (not on penalty) during the match? Otherwise we cannot compute the probability of scoring as it is given by $P(score) = P(score|penalty)P(penalty) + P(score|\neg penalty)P(\neg penalty)$.

Comment: I don't follow you, you have in your definition that a penalty is converted with $p=0.82$; what are you trying to compute? Is it the probability that at least one penalty is converted during a match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. The probability of at least one penalty being converted is 1 minus the probability
   that no penalties are converted
   $$ P(converted) = 1 - P(\neg converted)$$
2. No penalties are converted when **all** awarded penalties are failures.
   $$ P(\neg converted) = \sum_{awarded} P(\neg converted | awarded) P(awarded)$$
3. The awarded penalties are Poisson distributed.
   $$ P(awarded) = Po(\lambda)$$

EDIT:
Further details

- $G$: at least one penalty is converted
- $\neg G$: no penalty is converted
- $C_i$: $i$ penalties are converted
- $\neg C_i$: $i$ penalties are failed
- $A_i$: $i$ penalties are awarded

We have that
$$P(G) = 1 - P(\neg G);$$
note that no penalty is converted if, for any awarded penalty in the match, all the penalties are failures. The events $A_i$ are independent, so
$$P(\neg G) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty P(\neg C_i|A_i)P(A_i)$$
here, $P(\neg C_i|A_i)$ is the probability of failing $i$ penalty kicks; if we assume each kick is independent of the others,
$$P(\neg C_i |A_i) = (1-0.82)^i$$

Using the formula gives a probability of approximately $0.2796$ that at least one penalty is converted. The following small `julia` code shows that this is indeed the case

```
julia> using Distributions

julia> simulate(N) = begin
       p= 0.0
       for i in 1:N
           awarded = rand(Distributions.Poisson(0.4))
           if any(rand(awarded) .< 0.82)
               p += 1/N
           end
       end
       return p
       end
simulate (generic function with 1 method)

julia> simulate(10000000)
0.27953870000700837
```

Comment: $P(\neg converted | awarded)$ means that no penalties were converted given that $k$ penalties were awarded; Assuming that the conversion of penalties are independent, you have that $P(\neg converted | awarded = k) = (1-p)^k$ where $p$ is the probability that one penalty is converted ($p=0.82$).

Comment: you are missing the fact that it may be the case that no penalties are awarded.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The distribution of scored penalties in a match can be shown to have Poisson distribution again.

This time with rate: $$0.4\times(1-0.82)$$